# AnyChart : Uncaught ReferenceError: for multiple chart in single fragment

Tags: android, anychart

I am trying to display 3 charts on single fragment like below code.

But only one chart (3rd) is getting displayed and for first two charts it giving me error

```
E/TEST: Uncaught ReferenceError: circularGauge1 is not defined 
E/TEST: Uncaught ReferenceError: pareto32 is not defined
```

**My fragment ->**

```
 @Override
```

public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

```
setTypeWiseOrderChart();
setCustomerWiseOrderChart();
setStatusWiseOrderChart();
```

}
     private void setTypeWiseOrderChart(){

```
AnyChartView typeWiseOrderChartView = (AnyChartView) getView().findViewById(R.id.type_wise_order_chart_view);

CircularGauge circularGauge = AnyChart.circular();
circularGauge.data(new SingleValueDataSet(new String[] { "23", "34", "67", "93", "56", "100"}));
circularGauge.fill("#fff")
        .stroke(null)
        .padding(0d, 0d, 0d, 0d)
        .margin(100d, 100d, 100d, 100d);
circularGauge.startAngle(0d);
circularGauge.sweepAngle(270d);

Circular xAxis = circularGauge.axis(0)
        .radius(100d)
        .width(1d)
        .fill((Fill) null);
xAxis.scale()
        .minimum(0d)
        .maximum(100d);
xAxis.ticks("{ interval: 1 }")
        .minorTicks("{ interval: 1 }");
xAxis.labels().enabled(false);
xAxis.ticks().enabled(false);
xAxis.minorTicks().enabled(false);

circularGauge.label(0d)
        .text("Temazepam, <span style=\"\">32%</span>")
        .useHtml(true)
        .hAlign(HAlign.CENTER)
        .vAlign(VAlign.MIDDLE);
circularGauge.label(0d)
        .anchor(Anchor.RIGHT_CENTER)
        .padding(0d, 10d, 0d, 0d)
        .height(17d / 2d + "%")
        .offsetY(100d + "%")
        .offsetX(0d);
Bar bar0 = circularGauge.bar(0d);
bar0.dataIndex(0d);
bar0.radius(100d);
bar0.width(17d);
bar0.fill(new SolidFill("#64b5f6", 1d));
bar0.stroke(null);
bar0.zIndex(5d);
Bar bar100 = circularGauge.bar(100d);
bar100.dataIndex(5d);
bar100.radius(100d);
bar100.width(17d);
bar100.fill(new SolidFill("#F5F4F4", 1d));
bar100.stroke("1 #e5e4e4");
bar100.zIndex(4d);

circularGauge.label(1d)
        .text("Guaifenesin, <span style=\"\">34%</span>")
        .useHtml(true)
        .hAlign(HAlign.CENTER)
        .vAlign(VAlign.MIDDLE);
circularGauge.label(1d)
        .anchor(Anchor.RIGHT_CENTER)
        .padding(0d, 10d, 0d, 0d)
        .height(17d / 2d + "%")
        .offsetY(80d + "%")
        .offsetX(0d);
Bar bar1 = circularGauge.bar(1d);
bar1.dataIndex(1d);
bar1.radius(80d);
bar1.width(17d);
bar1.fill(new SolidFill("#1976d2", 1d));
bar1.stroke(null);
bar1.zIndex(5d);
Bar bar101 = circularGauge.bar(101d);
bar101.dataIndex(5d);
bar101.radius(80d);
bar101.width(17d);
bar101.fill(new SolidFill("#F5F4F4", 1d));
bar101.stroke("1 #e5e4e4");
bar101.zIndex(4d);

circularGauge.label(2d)
        .text("Salicylic Acid, <span style=\"\">67%</span>")
        .useHtml(true)
        .hAlign(HAlign.CENTER)
        .vAlign(VAlign.MIDDLE);
circularGauge.label(2d)
        .anchor(Anchor.RIGHT_CENTER)
        .padding(0d, 10d, 0d, 0d)
        .height(17d / 2d + "%")
        .offsetY(60d + "%")
        .offsetX(0d);
Bar bar2 = circularGauge.bar(2d);
bar2.dataIndex(2d);
bar2.radius(60d);
bar2.width(17d);
bar2.fill(new SolidFill("#ef6c00", 1d));
bar2.stroke(null);
bar2.zIndex(5d);
Bar bar102 = circularGauge.bar(102d);
bar102.dataIndex(5d);
bar102.radius(60d);
bar102.width(17d);
bar102.fill(new SolidFill("#F5F4F4", 1d));
bar102.stroke("1 #e5e4e4");
bar102.zIndex(4d);

circularGauge.label(3d)
        .text("Fluoride, <span style=\"\">93%</span>")
        .useHtml(true)
        .hAlign(HAlign.CENTER)
        .vAlign(VAlign.MIDDLE);
circularGauge.label(3d)
        .anchor(Anchor.RIGHT_CENTER)
        .padding(0d, 10d, 0d, 0d)
        .height(17d / 2d + "%")
        .offsetY(40d + "%")
        .offsetX(0d);
Bar bar3 = circularGauge.bar(3d);
bar3.dataIndex(3d);
bar3.radius(40d);
bar3.width(17d);
bar3.fill(new SolidFill("#ffd54f", 1d));
bar3.stroke(null);
bar3.zIndex(5d);
Bar bar103 = circularGauge.bar(103d);
bar103.dataIndex(5d);
bar103.radius(40d);
bar103.width(17d);
bar103.fill(new SolidFill("#F5F4F4", 1d));
bar103.stroke("1 #e5e4e4");
bar103.zIndex(4d);

circularGauge.label(4d)
        .text("Zinc Oxide, <span style=\"\">56%</span>")
        .useHtml(true)
        .hAlign(HAlign.CENTER)
        .vAlign(VAlign.MIDDLE);
circularGauge.label(4d)
        .anchor(Anchor.RIGHT_CENTER)
        .padding(0d, 10d, 0d, 0d)
        .height(17d / 2d + "%")
        .offsetY(20d + "%")
        .offsetX(0d);
Bar bar4 = circularGauge.bar(4d);
bar4.dataIndex(4d);
bar4.radius(20d);
bar4.width(17d);
bar4.fill(new SolidFill("#455a64", 1d));
bar4.stroke(null);
bar4.zIndex(5d);
Bar bar104 = circularGauge.bar(104d);
bar104.dataIndex(5d);
bar104.radius(20d);
bar104.width(17d);
bar104.fill(new SolidFill("#F5F4F4", 1d));
bar104.stroke("1 #e5e4e4");
bar104.zIndex(4d);

circularGauge.margin(50d, 50d, 50d, 50d);
circularGauge.title()
        .text("Medicine manufacturing progress' +\n" +
                "    '<br/><span style=\"color:#929292; font-size: 12px;\">(ACME CORPORATION)</span>")
        .useHtml(true);
circularGauge.title().enabled(true);
circularGauge.title().hAlign(HAlign.CENTER);
circularGauge.title()
        .padding(0d, 0d, 0d, 0d)
        .margin(0d, 0d, 20d, 0d);

typeWiseOrderChartView.setChart(circularGauge);
```

}

private void setCustomerWiseOrderChart(){

```
AnyChartView customerWiseOrderChartView = (AnyChartView) getView().findViewById(R.id.customer_wise_order_chart_view);

Pareto pareto = AnyChart.pareto();

List<DataEntry> data = new ArrayList<>();

data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Food is tasteless", 65));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Wait time", 109));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Unfriendly staff", 12.5));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Not clean", 45));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Overpriced", 250));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("To noisy", 27));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Food not fresh", 35));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Small portions", 170));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Not atmosphere", 35));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Food is to salty", 35));

pareto.data(data);

pareto.title("Pareto Chart of Restaurant Complaints");

pareto.yAxis(0d).title("Defect frequency");

pareto.yAxis(1d).title("Cumulative Percentage");

pareto.animation(true);

pareto.lineMarker(0)
        .value(80d)
        .axis(pareto.yAxis(1d))
        .stroke("#A5B3B3", 1d, "5 2", StrokeLineJoin.ROUND, StrokeLineCap.ROUND);

pareto.getSeries(0d).tooltip().format("Value: {%Value}");

Base line = pareto.getSeries(1d);
line.seriesType("spline")
        .markers(true);
line.labels().enabled(true);
line.labels()
        .anchor(Anchor.RIGHT_BOTTOM)
        .format("{%CF}%");
line.tooltip().format("Cumulative Frequency: {%CF}% \\n Relative Frequency: {%RF}%");

pareto.crosshair().enabled(true);
pareto.crosshair().xLabel(true);

customerWiseOrderChartView.setChart(pareto);
```

}

private void setStatusWiseOrderChart(){
    AnyChartView statusWiseOrderChartView = (AnyChartView) getView().findViewById(R.id.status_wise_order_chart_view);

```
Pie pie = AnyChart.pie();

pie.setOnClickListener(new ListenersInterface.OnClickListener(new String[]{"x", "value"}) {
    @Override
    public void onClick(Event event) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), event.getData().get("x") + ":" + event.getData().get("value"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

List<DataEntry> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Apples", 6371664));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Pears", 789622));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Bananas", 7216301));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Grapes", 1486621));
data.add(new ValueDataEntry("Oranges", 1200000));

pie.data(data);

pie.title("Fruits imported in 2015 (in kg)");

pie.labels().position("outside");

pie.legend().title().enabled(true);
pie.legend().title()
        .text("Retail channels")
        .padding(0d, 0d, 10d, 0d);

pie.legend()
        .position("center-bottom")
        .itemsLayout(LegendLayout.HORIZONTAL)
        .align(Align.CENTER);

statusWiseOrderChartView.setChart(pie);
```

}

**My Fragment view ->**

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".views.OrdersPlacedFragment"
android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <com.anychart.AnyChartView
        android:id="@+id/type_wise_order_chart_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        />

    <com.anychart.AnyChartView
        android:id="@+id/customer_wise_order_chart_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        />

    <com.anychart.AnyChartView
        android:id="@+id/status_wise_order_chart_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        />

</LinearLayout></androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: so many code please important part upload and proper format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time after the following code:

`AnyChartView anyChartView = findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view);`

You should add the following line:

`APIlib.getInstance().setActiveAnyChartView(anyChartView);`

Just like it was described in [this issue](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/issues/31).